# can't convert scraped string to float in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

so basically, I want to scrape a table from this article and find the difference between the 1980 column and the 2018 column. to do that, I'm trying to convert the scraped data from a tag to a string, and then to a float. but I get an error when I try to convert into a float.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_carbon_dioxide_emissions_per_capita")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.select('table:nth-of-type(2) tr:has(td)'):
    nation = tr.td.a.text
    eighty = tr.find_all("td")[3]
    eighty_x = eighty.text
    eighty_y = float(eighty_x)
    eighteen = tr.find_all("td")[14]
    eighteen_x = eighteen.text
    eighteen_y = float(eighteen_x)
    selection =(nation, eighty_x, eighteen_x.strip())
    print(selection)
```

what I get is this:

```
('Afghanistan', '0.2', '0.3')
('Albania', '1.7', '1.6')
('Algeria', '3.0', '3.9')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [39], in <cell line: 9>()
     11 eighty = tr.find_all("td")[3]
     12 eighty_x = eighty.text
---> 13 eighty_y = float(eighty_x)
     14 eighteen = tr.find_all("td")[14]
     15 eighteen_x = eighteen.text

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '..'
```

Comment: The error seems self explanatory - some fields are "..", which isn't a valid floating point number.  You should check for that (or handle the exception), and, eg, replace with 0.

Answer (score 1):

The table that you're scraping from, located here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_carbon_dioxide_emissions_per_capita

has the ".." in it. So that's the issue. You then need to decide how to handle that case. Maybe store it as a -1 in your data to signal the lack of data in the table? Up to you.

Also, I think in your `selection` you want `eighty_y` and `eighteen_y` instead of the `x`'s right? Or else why are you turning `x->y` (as in `eighty_x` becomes `eighty_y`)?

Assuming this is fine, then this will do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_carbon_dioxide_emissions_per_capita")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.select('table:nth-of-type(2) tr:has(td)'):
    if tr is None or tr.td is None or tr.td.a is None: continue
    nation = tr.td.a.text
    eighty = tr.find_all("td")[3]
    eighty_x = eighty.text
    eighty_y = -1 if ".." in eighty_x else float(eighty_x)
    eighteen = tr.find_all("td")[14]
    eighteen_x = eighteen.text
    eighteen_y = -1 if ".." in eighteen_x else float(eighteen_x)
    selection =(nation, eighty_y, eighteen_y)
    print(selection)
```